# Configuring user profile sync service

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service

I am working on configuring the User profile sync service (As in the services on server page) but is "stuck on starting".

Anyway, this service uses the farm account (where I installed Sharepoint under). Do I give this account the replicate changes permissions? The ups service app has the domainnetbiosnamesenabled property set to true/1 (my fqdn and netbios name for the domain are not the same).

I have a default instance name of sql server (MSSQLSERVER), and my fqdn/netbios names are not the same (I ran the powershell script to enable netbiosnames).

Anyway, my question is:

This service runs under the farm account (The account I installed sharepoint under). Do I therefore need to give this account the replicate directory changes permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Plan for profile synchronization (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182925.aspx#permission)

> The synchronization account for a connection to Active Directory
>   Domain Services (AD DS) must have the following permissions:
>
> It must have **Replicate Directory Changes permission** on the domain that
>   you will synchronize with. For more information, see the Grant
>   Replicate Directory Changes permission on a domain section of the
>   "Grant Active Directory Domain Services permissions for profile
>   synchronization" procedural reference article.

And

> The Replicate Directory Changes permission allows an account to query
>   for the changes in the directory. This permission does not allow an
>   account to make any changes in the directory.

Also I suggest you to use dedicated account for user profile service in any 'serious scenario'. For testing purposes using farm account is ok.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes up so many times its not funny; as always start with Habars site and try all those fixes first

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

I've also had firewall related issues effect UPS.